# How does the int and char pointer affect my print out here?

Tags: c, pointers

so here is the code, till the 4th print out I easily followed it, but at the 5th print out, I don't understand

why its `"5: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 128144, a[2] = 256, a[3] = 302 "`?

I have commented the line in the code which I don't understand. I look forward to your response.

```
"#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
f(void)
{
    int a[4];
    int *b = malloc(16);
    int *c = 0;
    int i;

    printf("1: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);

    c = a;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    a[i] = 100 + i;

    c[0] = 200;
    printf("2: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c[1] = 300;
    *(c + 2) = 301;

    3[c] = 302;
    printf("3: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    c = c + 1;
    *c = 400;

    printf("4: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    //I DONT UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS LINE BELOW DOES
    c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);

    *c = 500;
    printf("5: a[0] = %d, a[1] = %d, a[2] = %d, a[3] = %d\n",
       a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);

    b = (int *) a + 1;
    c = (int *) ((char *) a + 1);
    printf("6: a = %p, b = %p, c = %p\n", a, b, c);
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}



output:
1: a = 0x7fff65fdcb90, b = 0x1065007e0, c = 0x0
2: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 101, a[2] = 102, a[3] = 103
3: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 300, a[2] = 301, a[3] = 302
4: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 400, a[2] = 301, a[3] = 302
5: a[0] = 200, a[1] = 128144, a[2] = 256, a[3] = 302
6: a = 0x7fff65fdcb90, b = 0x7fff65fdcb94, c = 0x7fff65fdcb91
```

Comment: That's the beauty of C :) - Actually, that increments the pointer `c` by one byte, instead of incrementing by four bytes, as `c + 1` would.

Comment: Why would someone ever want to do that in programming?

Comment: You'd be surprised. casting pointers is something I do quite regularily

Comment: I understand you might cast pointers, but for regular high level programming, is such tedious manipulation really necessary? I hail from a Java background, and while I understand the concept of pointers; I can't quite fathom why someone would want to move the pointer over by a byte, add some value, and continue on with their day. Perhaps I am missing the point, hence my intellectual curiosity.

Comment: That cracked me up ^^ - The specific point illustrated in the example is quite pointless, I agree. However, this concept can easily be applied to other situations. Imagine an array of 2-tuples, each with a width of 2 byte, a C programmer may find it convenient to use an array of int, and cast some pointers to short* to be able to acces the values of the 2-tuples separately, without using some kind of higher level construct, or shift operations. It's just another way of doing things. (Also, many C programmers take pride in obfuscating)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with the basics.

`c` is a pointer to an array of `int`s.

Let this be `a`:

```
[00000000][00000000][00000000][00000000]
```

Every two digits is a byte, and we assume that `sizeof(int)` is 4 in our example, so every element in `a` has 4 bytes, or 8 digits.

Now, `c` is a pointer to the first element in `a`.

Let's have a look at the expression in question:

```
c = (int *) ((char *) c + 1);
```

Obviously, `c` is changed here, but what exactly happens is:

1. `c` is cast from `int*` to `char*`
2. the result of the cast is incremented, resulting in `sizeof(char)` being added to `c`. Since `sizeof(char)` is `1`, `c` is incremented by 1 and points to the **second byte** of an element in `a`.
3. the result is cast back to `int*`, and reassigned to `c`. This second cast is actually not needed.

So, ignoring all the other code, we start from this:

```
a : [00000000][00000000]...
     ^
  c -|
```

And go to this:

```
a : [00000000][00000000]...
       ^
  c ---|
```

As Daniel pointed out below, if c is not correctly aligned for a pointer of type `int*`, you get **undefined behaviour**, which should be avoided.

Comment: "c is incremented, resulting in `sizeof(*c)` being added to `c`. Since `c` is of type `char*`" That's not correct. `c` is always an `int*`. What happens is that 1 is added to the (unnamed) result of the cast, sort of like `{ char *tmp = (char*)c; c = (int*)(tmp + 1); }`. And you should probably mention that that may lead to undefined behaviour due to `(char*)c + 1` not being properly aligned.

Comment: @DanielFischer of course you're right. I did that for the sake of simplicity. Do you have a reference for the UB?

Comment: I know you did that for simplicity;) I just thought you have oversimplified a bit. Regarding the UB, 6.3.2.3 (7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined." Whether `c = (int*)((char*)c + 1);` does indeed invoke UB depends on the implementation, of course.

Answer (score 3):

`c` is a pointer-to-int, so normally `c+1` refers to the address which is `sizeof(int)` further along in memory - usually 4 bytes on a 32-bit system.

But you cast `c` to `char*` - that is, pointer-to-char. Now, `char` is only 1 byte long, so `(char *)c + 1` refers to the memory location *1 byte* further on than `c`; which is *in the middle of* the `int` at `c`.

You then cast the result back to an `int*` and write 500 into it. So what you're doing is (probably) writing the 4-byte representation of 500 over the last 3 bytes of `a[1]` and the 1st byte of `a[2]`. Exactly what effect that will have depends on the endianness of your system, but that's basically what's going on.